# Issue Reading Multiple Keys From Firebase for Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble reading multiple keys from my database. These keys are all children of a userID key, however, when I code to get the value of they key, it only returns the value of the one most recently saved to the ListView.

For context, this is for a sports app, and each key is a team name. With this code, it only returns the most recently saved team name, even though the others are shown in the database. This team name is inputted by the user, and the name is set to a variable which is then saved to the database as a key. It is not saved to a java class.

My code for reading is as follows:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Log.i("snap", "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

           for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               for(DataSnapshot team: ds.getChildren()) {

                   String key = team.getKey();

                   Log.i("my team", team.toString());

                   ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
                   array.add(key);
                   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(StatisticsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                   listViewTeam.setAdapter(adapter);

               }
           }
           dataSnapshot.getValue();

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Any tips or recommendations on how I can get this to return more than just the most recently saved key would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then your problem lies that you are creating array list inside the for loop and you are adding one item every item to it i.e. you are adding one item to arraylist and each time you add an element and set up the adapter. so at the end of loop there is one item in the list.
basically you should initialise your arrayList outside the for loop and wile iterating add element to it. And when all elements are added then set your adapter.

You should do something like below.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Log.i("snap", "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

           for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               for(DataSnapshot team: ds.getChildren()) {

                   String key = team.getKey();

                   Log.i("my team", team.toString());


                   array.add(key);


               }
           }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(StatisticsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listViewTeam.setAdapter(adapter);
        dataSnapshot.getValue();//I think this is not needed in your code.

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

Comment: Hi Anuj. This worked perfectly! If I could ask you one more question, however, do you know how I could specify to get only the values for the user signed in? I already have the FirebaseAuth and getCurrentUser() definied, I just need to know how to get the child of that specific key. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I am not sure about your business logic to define a signed user and the structure of DataSnapShot class . Basically if value is present then while iterating you should compare the signed value of each user to parameter which says its signed. and add only that to list or whatever way you want to handle it.